# Using a custom authorization attribute within a function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a custom authorization attribute that works great in my C# / MVC4.

Problem now is that I need to use this attribute in a function, not just ahead of the function to route a webpage only if the user is a member of a certain custom authorization attribute.

This would be an example of my custom attribute usage ahead of a function in MVC4

```
[isAuthorized(enRole = new oRoles[] { oRoles.PageAdmin, oRoles.PageEditor })]
```

However, I need to use that attribute in an if statement.

Like:

```
if (isAuthorized(enRole = new oRoles[] { oRoles.PageAdmin, oRoles.Super })
    return RedirectToAction("Admin","PageEditor");
```

The error I get is this:
AuthCheck is a type but is used like a 'variable'

Can I use my custom attribute like this?

Comment: I'd say you probably should refactor your attribute code so that most (if not all) of its logic lives in a class method somewhere where you can call it from both the attribute and the new function you now need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be like this:

```
if(User.IsInRole(oRoles.PageAdmin) || User.IsInRole(oRoles.Super))
  return RedirectToAction("Admin","PageEditor");
```

Comment: oRoles is an enum and User.IsInRole( string )...

        public enum oRoles
    {
        User = 1,
        PageAdmin = 2,
        .....

Comment: Write the method to get role name for given enum value: string GetRoleName(oRoles role) {...}.

Comment: I'm an idiot...  I have a function that I wrote months back that does this checking with User.IsInRole(...) and the groups.  You are correct sir.  Thanks for your help.